# iOS App using iCloud storage is adding .icloud file extension to my documents

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, uidocument, nsfilewrapper

In my iOS (swift 3.0) mobile application, the device creating a document to store in iCloud is able to load and manipulate the file again. Once iCloud transfers the file(s) to another device, they are no longer able to open and have a "." prepended to the original file name AND .icloud appended to the end.

My document structure is as follows:

*Project_Name.spp* (directory file wrapper) holding a *project.data* file and additional directory file wrappers *Page_Name.spg* containing *page.meta*, *page.plist*, and *screenshot.jpg*

Except for the root directory file wrapper, all files are renamed as similar to: *.project.data.icloud*

This was not happening previously so I'm not certain what code update would have created this behavior. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The files are in the process of being downloaded by the iCloud sync process. Did you call `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem` on the parent directory?